# Unable to Fetch User Data with FB Login via Native App - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated FB Sdk. When I am trying to login via native FB App. It prompts open Facebook App. When I say "YES", it launched the FB App, It says you have already given permission or give permission. At that time FB login manager is called, when I say "OK", It returns to my app and nothing happens.

How to handle this issue and how to fetch user data?

BR,

Erdem

Comment: The SFSafariViewController's parent view controller was dismissed.
This can happen if you are triggering login from a UIAlertController. Instead, make sure your top most view controller will not be prematurely dismissed. - This is the log I am taking.